# Loop through dataframe to identify subgroup and label with unique identifier

Tags: pandas, database, dataframe, loops

I'm trying to complete the `Sessions` column with a unique integer per session for further processing.

A session is defined by one day or a period from 9:30-16:00

```
        Symbol                Time   Open   High    Low  Close  Volume  LOD  Sessions
2724312   AEHR 2019-09-23 09:31:00   1.42   1.42   1.42   1.42     200  NaN       NaN
2724313   AEHR 2019-09-23 09:43:00   1.35   1.35   1.34   1.34    6062  NaN       NaN
2724314   AEHR 2019-09-23 09:58:00   1.35   1.35   1.29   1.30    8665  NaN       NaN
2724315   AEHR 2019-09-23 09:59:00   1.32   1.32   1.32   1.32     100  NaN       NaN
2724316   AEHR 2019-09-23 10:00:00   1.35   1.35   1.35   1.35     400  NaN       NaN
...        ...                 ...    ...    ...    ...    ...     ...  ...       ...
```

I've tried everything using `loop` but I keep getting every KeyError and SettingWithCopyWarning in the book.

---

Edit: Error & Code added

SettingWithCopyWarning:

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
> https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
> self._setitem_single_block(indexer, value, name)

```
df = df
# Columns ['Symbol', 'Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'LOD', 'Sessions']

# Add Date column to loop through
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time']).dt.date

previous_session = df['Date'].iloc[0]
prev_sesh_count = 1

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    current_session = df['Date'].iloc[i]
    if previous_session == current_session:
        df['Sessions'].iloc[i] = prev_sesh_count
    else:
        df['Sessions'].iloc[i] = prev_sesh_count + 1
        prev_sesh_count = prev_sesh_count + 1
```

Comment: The problem is not how to fill the `Sessions` column but how did you get this dataframe. Your current dataframe is a slice of a previous dataframe. To debug, you have to update your post with your code. Not all code but there where you made a copy of your dataframe. You should use `.iloc` and `.loc` to subsetting your dataframe

Comment: apologies. error & code now added

Comment: You have chained assignment with `df['Sessions'].iloc[i]` it should be `df.loc[i, 'Sessions']` as indicated by the error message.

Comment: Thanks Henry, that has corrected the error, however, the code now won't stop running. There are 3.3 million lines. Other simple operations take about 20 seconds but 10 minutes have already passed here

Comment: @AnthonyShi Do you want to assign session per `Symbol` or for the complete dataframe?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma complete dataframe. i.e the first session number for ABCD `Symbol` should *not* equal the first session number of WXYZ `Symbol`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the dataframe is sorted on `Date`, we can use `duplicated` along with `cumsum` to assign the unqiue sessions numbers

```
df['Sessions'] = (~df.duplicated(['Symbol', 'Date'])).cumsum()
```

---

```
print(df)

        Symbol                 Time  Open  High   Low  Close  Volume  LOD  Sessions        Date
2724312   AEHR  2019-09-23 09:31:00  1.42  1.42  1.42   1.42     200  NaN         1  2019-09-23
2724313   AEHR  2019-09-23 09:43:00  1.35  1.35  1.34   1.34    6062  NaN         1  2019-09-23
2724314   AEHR  2019-09-23 09:58:00  1.35  1.35  1.29   1.30    8665  NaN         1  2019-09-23
2724315   AEHR  2019-09-23 09:59:00  1.32  1.32  1.32   1.32     100  NaN         1  2019-09-23
2724316   AEHR  2019-09-23 10:00:00  1.35  1.35  1.35   1.35     400  NaN         1  2019-09-23
```